# How to inform users that his browser is not supported

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, browser, cross-browser, google-chrome

I'm working at a small company and we are developing a web
application. With the very few resources we have available, we can't afford
to assemble the development team we would like to (we are only two people).
The web app is becoming very complex over time and it is very difficult
to keep progress with IEx, Firefox, Safari, and others. We try to be clean
at coding so we have an almost functional web app for all non IEx modern
browsers, but IE is another story.

How do we inform users that IE is not supported at all and they should
install a modern browser to continue?

Please keep in mind that the question isn't if we should or should not
support IE. Because we won't. The question is how to inform the users
to change browser.

Currently we have a small white box on top of page that displays
some text and has some links to Firefox and Chrome. Do you
have any ideas on how to achieve this? Anyone who has addressed this
problem before and has some experience?

Comment: Wait, are you talking about IE6 or every version of IE?

Comment: There are hundreds of thousands of corporate employees who are not able to change their browser, and who will be irritated by your suggestion that they do that.

Comment: You can ignore IE? I'm jealous...

Comment: I can understand not supporting IE 6, but 7 and 8 are pretty good these days.  You'll definitely be hurting your customer base, methinks.

Comment: Not supporting IE6 I find justifiable. Not supporting IE at all, not. Could be a big mistake. I hate fixing the tons of discrepancies as well, but it is becoming increasingly easier with every new version.

Comment: You are pretty brave if you exclude +60% of all web users. Or you have a very, very desirable product that will make people download a new browser. (Downloading a new browser excludes almost all corporate users)

Comment: Not everybody cares about attracting Windows users.

Comment: You are my hero! I have tears in my eyes. 2010 can come, with brave people like you!

Comment: For the critics: You don't know his demographics. Only 19.2% of users of this site use Internet Explorer: http://www.heise.de/open/meldung/Marktforscher-Firefox-3-5-ueberholt-Internet-Explorer-7-890932.html

Comment: Any reason why you have changed your decision of which answer to accept?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Do you support a gracefully reduced subset of functionality on IE?

If so, pop up a warning message the first time the user sees the app, stating that due to technical limitation of Internet Explorer software, the app's functionality is reduced

if not, display an explicit error page stating that another browser is needed.

2) Do your potential users have a great level of trust in you?

if Joe Schmoe web page comes in and tells me to install XXX, I will tell that web page "no".

So the best approach is to link to some TRUSTED web source explaining non-IE browsers and how to install them, either instead of in addition to your own instructions.

Comment: See [cyril's answer re browser-update.org](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19532152/199364), for a complete implementation of this approach.

Answer (score 8):

IE supports conditional comments, which is kind of weird, but it will work in this case.  You can do something like this:

```
<!--[if IE]> Get a better browser! <![endif]-->
```

To any other browser (FF, chrome, safari, etc.) This will just look like a normal HTML comment and will be ignored, however IE will actually evaluate the statement and render what you ask it to.

Edit:  Check the [MSDN article on conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx) for more information.  This feature has been around since IE 5, so it's pretty safe and reliable to use.

Comment: The idea of the question is how to inform the user, not how to detect user browser. Thanks for the answer anyway, haven't tried IE conditionals yet.

Comment: That's exactly what this enables.  Whatever is inside the comments will be rendered to the user if they're using IE, so for example if you place some markup inside that conditional comment, you will effectively notify your IE users that "Hey, you really shouldn't use this browser," whereas your other users won't see anything.  If this isn't what you were after, I appologize for misunderstanding.

Comment: I guess you were looking for a more philosophical answer such as the verbiage to use, or how to explain it clearly.

Comment: apparently this doens't work in IE 10+ :(

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/ms537512(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 4):

Well although i don't recommend you to do this display them this image:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gosquared.com](http://www.gosquared.com/liquidicity/wp-content/uploads/2007/05/lq_how_to_pie_2.jpg))</sub>

and say **"Instead of wasting time with IE, we choose to ......."** (get things done etc...)

And provide few web browser download link. Do not provide many, people can get confused.

Also you can provide some links such as: http://stopie.wordpress.com/

Comment: -1 because stopie hasn't been updated in a while and the image you posted is not that self explanatory. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I did not provide stopie link to put your web site, please read the answer again. I told you to find a relevant web site, if not provide why not supporting IE yourself it is clear. I thought that the image explains the reason of not supporting IE for your application. Since you did not provide the reason of not supporting it i cannot say anything else. And you are welcome.

Comment: Sorry jcasso, maybe I shouldn't voted down. I don't think the image is relevant enough, from users' perspective.

Answer (score 3):

Consider supporting Chrome Frame for people who are forced to use IE6 (in a corporate environment).

And while it's totally understandable to not support IE6, if you can't support IE8, you're doing something wrong.  It should be very little work to make a standards-based web app work on IE8 after it already works on Firefox and WebKit.

Comment: To the contrary, IE8 does not support many current standards and practices that are available on all the other major browsers and I perfectly understand why one would not support it. It doesn't natively support SVG, XHTML served as XHTML, parts of the DOM, javascript and so on (don't want to make a list). Even the parts it does support, it does poorly or incorrectly. In any case, this whole thread is not about whether he should support IE or not.

Comment: NOTE: Chrome Frame is discontinued. [Google recommends not using it.](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started): *"If you have Chrome Frame installed, please uninstall it. It is no longer supported or updated."*

Answer (score 3):

People always install additional software and clients to use different services. But when you propose another browser they sometimes become hostile.

Try to find a wording that explains that this is just another piece of software, another client, and that they don't need to abandon their beloved Internet Explorer. They just need a current browser for your site/web application.

Installing Google Chrome and Firefox additional to an existing Internet Explorer is as easy as installing the new version of GET-ME-PORN and I-DON'T-PAY-FOR-MUSIC.

Something like this:

> To use this web application you need to use another client. Please start Firefox >= 3.5, Google Chrome, Safari >= 4, or Opera >= 9 and visit this address again.
>
> You can install any current browser additional to Internet Explorer without problems. Just start the downloaded installer like any other installer. Internet Explorer doesn't get affected! Don't change the default browser, if you don't want to.

You could link the browser names to the download pages.

And to the critics: Can you take part in [Second Life](http://secondlife.com/) with your browser? Can you play World of Warcraft in your browser?

Comment: Well, ever since tabbed browsing appeared opening another browser just for a single site is kind of a nuisance. You don't boot up another OS for every other application you use, do you? And you'd probably be rightfully repelled by someone who suggests you should.

Comment: Very similar answer to DVK's but I think this one is more detailed.

Comment: @Johannes Rössel: Most IE users have no problem starting Outlook (Express) for e-mail.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery, detecting IE is as simple as:

```
if ( $.browser.msie )
 alert( 'Unfortunately, you are using Internet Explorer, which is obsolete...' );
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers are a bit outdated, and its the first hit when asking google how to check outdated browser from a web appli, so here below is the solution I found the more elegant.

There is a nice and non-intrusive alternative which is to embed the check proposed by [browser-update.org](http://browser-update.org/#install). The web site will redirect the user to the latest version of each browser. User can then select the brand he feels more familiar with.

I understand OP wanted specificaly to disqualify IE browser, but since 3 years the situation has evolve and the IE 10 version in -quite- usable now and could be considered as an alternative to the other browser for a modern web appli.

Comment: UPDATE: Now that IE is no longer maintained, and has fallen behind in feature support (and security?), there is again a need to direct people to other browsers. I see that browser-update.org does have an option for saying that a given browser is not supported - in any version - by your website. (I haven't tested.)

Comment: Is there any way of doing this easily that anyone has found @ToolmakerSteve

Answer (score 0):

IE's conditional comments are more reliable than user agent strings.

`<!--[if IE ]> Go away <![endif]-->`

Comment: Again, how to inform users, not how to detect user browser.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the mechanics of how to do it, it looks like the MSIE conditional comments will allow you to handle that.

Regarding the wording, be cautious.  You don't want to annoy people, even if you don't support their browser.  You should probably recommend something like "This site works best using Firefox, Safari, Opera or Chrome".  If your site will work under MSIE but not as elegantly, then say so - carefully.

One of the internal corporate sites I have to use does not support Firefox on MacOS X (and it renders lousily in the browser - I've not investigated why; it works fine with Firefox on XP, but I only occasionally boot the XP machine these days, mainly to keep it more or less up to date with security patches).  It pops up a dialogue box telling me as much, but allows me to continue.  The stuff works - it just looks rotten.